# R make `table` command work with additional `amount` column

Tags: r, dataframe, data-analysis, counting

I'm working with R and data like this

```
data <- data.frame(name=c("dog", "cat", "steak", "dog", "mouse", "cat"), amount=c(1, 2, 2.5, 1, 4, 1))
```

Thus my data looks like this

> ```
> > data
>    name amount
> 1   dog    1.0
> 2   cat    2.0
> 3 steak    2.5
> 4   dog    1.0
> 5 mouse    4.0
> 6   cat    1.0
> ```

Now I want to count how many objects I have (`dog`'s, `cat`'s, etc). Normally I would just use the `table`-function.

```
> table(data$name)

  cat   dog mouse steak 
    2     2     1     1
```

But as you can image I don't just want to count how many entries there are in the data frame. I want to count in the `amount` column. I'd like output like this

```
> custom_table(data)

  cat   dog mouse steak 
  3.0   2.0   4.0   2.5
```

Is there an easy way to get this kind of `table`-function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table` gives the frequency count, we need to get the `sum` grouped by 'name'

```
aggregate(amount ~ name, data, sum)
#   name amount
#1   cat    3.0
#2   dog    2.0
#3 mouse    4.0
#4 steak    2.5
```

---

Or if we need a named `vector`

```
with(data, tapply(amount, name, FUN = sum))
#  cat   dog mouse steak 
#  3.0   2.0   4.0   2.5
```

---

Or with `count` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data  %>%
     count(name, wt = amount)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using     `dyplr`:

```
library(dyplr)

data %>% group_by(name) %>% tally(amount)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  name      n
  <fct> <dbl>
1 cat     3  
2 dog     2  
3 mouse   4  
4 steak   2.5
```